# Resource not found errors being generated by Chrome at the server side

Tags: google-chrome, http-status-code-404

I recently install the wonderful elmah (http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) and am struggling identifying a really strange error which elmah catches.

It looks to be Chrome specific. I can re-create at will in Chrome but not in Firefox or IE.

I have some paths to images and javascript in my master pages as follows:

The page I create the error on is http://mysite.com/home/

In the source of this page I can see the js is being loaded properly in Chrome - the dev tools don't report any 404's etc. Also when I copy the link to the js from the source and open it in a new window - it loads the right path.

Yet, elmah catches and error where the client tried to call:

/home/js/jquery.js

Really really odd - has anyone experienced this with Chrome before?

Answer (score 0):

It may be on of the two:

1. you use jquery in your code, and instead of /js/jquery.js you load it from js/jquery.js (note the lack of / at the beginning
2. you have an extension in Chrome that injects jQuery as a [content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) in a wrong way. Try disabling  all extension and then try again to see if the error is still there

Comment: Hi Nicolae = it's not no. 1 because dev tools would be reporting a 404 on the incorrect path if that was the case - it's not. I don't think I'm running any extensions injecting jquery etc. but i'll take a look - would never have thought of that! I'll also try chrome on a different machine too.